# How to group a pyspark dataframe and use a shift operator as aggregation method?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have the following dataframe :

| ride | window_left | window_right | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | No | No | 1 |
| 1 | No | Yes | 2 |
| 1 | Yes | Yes | 3 |
| 1 | Yes | Yes | 4 |
| 2 | No | No | 1 |
| 2 | Yes | No | 2 |
| 2 | Yes | Yes | 3 |
| 2 | Yes | Yes | 4 |
| 2 | Yes | Yes | 5 |

And I would like to group this pyspark dataframe by the column `ride` and shift either `window_left` or `window_right` according to which one takes the value `Yes` first, like that :

| ride | window_left | window_right | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | No | No | 1 |
| 1 | Yes | Yes | 2 |
| 1 | Yes | Yes | 3 |
| 1 | None | Yes | 4 |
| 2 | No | No | 1 |
| 2 | Yes | Yes | 2 |
| 2 | Yes | Yes | 3 |
| 2 | Yes | Yes | 4 |
| 2 | Yes | None | 5 |

I would like to use pyspark only to perform this transformation. I cannot use pandas, and that's why I have some difficulties. The tricky part for me is to shift after grouping, knowing that the shift depends on the group.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Comment: " shift either window_left or window_right according to which one takes the value Yes first": sorry I do not really understand the rule you try to implement, and I do not see any 'grouping' in your example. Could you please be more precise?

Comment: @Christophe Yes, this is a language abuse, sorry. But if you look to the tables, you'll understand what I want to do. If window_right is takes Yes as value before window_left, I want to shift window_left back so that they both take Yes as value.

Comment: This means a 'case' statement should so the job, for that you might use [`when()`](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-when-otherwise/) function

Comment: The logic won't work safely. It would work for this small sample case but Spark dataframe is unordered because Spark is meant to be parallel processes. That means unless you have unique ID or some kind of column that you can order upon, row of "No" or "Yes" _can_ be swapped.

Comment: If I have a time column which can help me to order the data according to the value of ride, is it possible to sort the spark dataframe ?

Comment: Yes, could you update your sample data with the time column?

Comment: Hmm, this is complex. I cannot come up with a window function to combine with the condition + the lag offset.